# How to load data file in Cordova plugin?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am developing a Cordova plugin that comes with some data files. I need these files to

1. Be copied to the mobile device, and
2. Be loaded the files in the runtime.

What I am currently doing is to define these files in plugin.xml as resource files, like:

```
<resource-file src="assets/data.xml" target="assets/data.xml"/>
```

However, I do not know how to open these files in my Android Java code. If I use a `File` class to open the file, what path should I use?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one has answered this question after a few days, and I have not found a solution elsewhere, I am going to post my own workaround here.

1. Package all the data files with directory in a zip file.
2. Put zip file in the Cordova app.
3. When the app starts up for the 1st time, the app uploads the zip file to the plug-in, using a FileTransfer plug-in.
4. The plug-in unzips the file in the application's sandbox.

I have to admit that this is not a decent solution. It makes the plug-in depend on the app. However, if there is no better solution, this one just works.

Still, if there is a better solution, please post share it here.